# Getting a total for values in cells

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view that keeps track of hotel receipts (each time the user enters the date, cost, and name of the hotel and hits the add button it adds a new row to the table with the information.

I have 2 text fields below the table that I want to show the total entries (number of rows) and the sum of the cost field. Problem is I can't figure out how to do this or if it is even possible.

I have found a couple posts about it but they all seem to have a set number of rows.

```
extension HotelViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
    return numberOfSections!

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let numberOfRows = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    return numberOfRows!

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HotelCell", for: indexPath) as! HotelTableViewCell
    let item = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! DriveAwayHotel

    cell.date.text = item.date
    cell.name.text = item.name
    cell.cost.text = "$\(item.cost ?? 0.00)"

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let managedObject : NSManagedObject = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    pc.delete(managedObject)

    do {

        try pc.save()

    } catch {

        print(error)
        return

    }

}
```

[image: Hotel receipt view controller]

Comment: share your code that handle  tables row , what is your data sources

Comment: The data is in your data model, not the cells.

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to do math on your cells. You should do math on your model.

Are you trying to sum all the entries in your table, or just the cells that are visible?

If you want to sum all the entries in your table view, then loop through all the sections in your frc.sections array, loop through all the entries in each section, and add them all up. (That code would be easy to write.)

If you only want to sum the entries for the currently visible cells, call the table view's `indexPathsForVisibleRows` method to get an array of the indexPaths of the cells that are visible, loop through those indexPaths, fetch the entry at each section and row, and add **those** together. (That code would also be easy to write.)

### EDIT:

The code to sum all your entries might look something like the below (I'm having to guess a bit since I don't know your data model)

```
var total = 0.0
guard let sections = frc.sections?.count else { return }
for section in 0..<sections {
  guard let rows = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects else { continue }
  for row in 0..<rows {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
    let item = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! DriveAwayHotel
    total += item.cost
  }
}
```

Comment: As the user adds a new receipt to the table I want it to add the cost...... Maybe this was a bad question or worded poorly.

Comment: So it sounds like you always want to show the total of all values. So lop through the sections, and through each entry in each section, and add the values. Can you post the definition of your frc object?

Comment: Sorry..... I didn't give very good information on this one. All my data is being saved in an entity named hotelreceipts.  
var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()